# Embed google analytics in my asp.net 4.5.2 web forms site

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have a asp.net web forms site and I need if possible to be able to "embed" my google analytics into an asp.net page (e.g stats.aspx).

I have read many articles and all seem really complicated or just don't work.

For example:-
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/119/displaying-google-analytics-data-in-asp-net

Does anyone have (if there is such a thing) a really simple example to embed bar bones google analytics data to my page?

Comment: the blog referred to is quite old, you now have Embed API that you can embed directly, based on JS, link to official GA Embed link - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

Comment: Thanks yes I have seen that but it is far from clear (to me):-

a) How to use the google embed api with asp.net

b) How to obtain the client id etc

Comment: you would have to be clear on what you want to achieve, the question is quite generic